# How to get AspectRatio(or orientation) of youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question about youtube javscript API.

I want to get aspectRatio of specified video not mine.

I have been found the information about aspectRatio property of contentDetails at getting-started-guide(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

[example ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzjQl.png)

But I don't find this aspectRatio property when I access this (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&key=API_KEY)

Can only videos owner select video's aspectRatio by fileDetails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Only owners of the video are able to access the `fileDetails` properties - that includes the `aspectRatio`. If you try to make a [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=fileDetails&id=s3GKxnBDu2g&_h=13&) request asking for fileDetails, you'll get this error response:

```
"message": "The request is not properly authorized to access video file or processing information. Note that the <code>fileDetails</code>, <code>processingDetails</code>, and <code>suggestions</code> parts are only available to that videos owner."
```